# Bash: Convert non-ASCII characters to ASCII

Tags: bash, ascii

How can I convert a string like `Žvaigždės aukštybėj užges` or `äüöÖÜÄ` to `Zvaigzdes aukstybej uzges` or `auoOUA`, respectively, using Bash?

Basically I just want to convert all characters which aren't in the Latin alphabet.

Thanks

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Depending on your machine you can try piping your strings through

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//translit
```

(or whatever your encoding is, if it's not utf-8)

Comment: echo "Aldo Vásquez" | iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//translit
Aldo V'asquez  . running this through the app I"m trying to match , it outputs "Aldo_Vasquez" how would I get iconv to do that?

Comment: @majorgear, honestly — no idea. This particular case can be handled by something like `echo "Aldo Vásquez" | tr 'ÁáÉé' 'AaEe'`, but it's hardly a solution to write home about…

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to replicate the output of  an app I was using.  Its open source so I’m just going to have to dig into the code to find how it’s doing the conversion.

Answer (score 18):

You might be able to use iconv.

For example, the string:

> Žvaigždės aukštybėj užges or äüöÖÜÄ

is in file testutf8.txt, utf8 format.

Running command:

`iconv -f UTF8 -t US-ASCII//TRANSLIT testutf8.txt`

results in:

> Zvaigzdes aukstybej uzges or auoOUA

Answer (score 8):

```
echo Hej på dig, du den dära | iconv -f utf-8 -t us-ascii//TRANSLIT
```

gives:

```
Hej pa dig, du den dara
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the python library [unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) to perform so:

```
$ echo "Žvaigždės aukštybėj užges äüöÖÜÄ" | unidecode
```

Output:

```
Zvaigzdes aukstybej uzges auoOUA
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969201/how-to-romanize-transliterate-unidecode-strings-in-bash) for other approaches.

Answer (score -1):

```
 try {
        String name = "Žvaigždės aukštybėj užges ";
        String s1 = Normalizer.normalize(name, Normalizer.Form.NFKD);
        String regex = "[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}\\p{IsLm}\\p{IsSk}]+";

        String s2 = new String(s1.replaceAll(regex, "").getBytes("ascii"), "ascii");

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    }
```

Comment: Easy to criticise this, but a newbie took the effort, got shouted down and has now left SO. [Slow clap..] And what would we do without iconv?

Comment: @geotheory: ...and it's not like the other answers are pure bash, either. They all rely on an external executable. All this answer really needs is instructions to compile the java file and run it from bash.