# change lowercase file names to uppercase with awk ,sed or bash

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I would like to change lowercase filenames to uppercase with awk/sed/bash

your help would be appreciated

```
aaaa.txt
vvjv.txt
acfg.txt
```

desired output

```
AAAA.txt
VVJV.txt
ACFG.txt
```

Comment: 1.I used these tips to change my funny filenames with a bash one-liner: for i in ./*.*; do mv "$i" "$(echo "$i" | tr '[:?=&]' '[_]')"; done ; 2.Cross reference fyi to deal with even weird unicode chars: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011569/how-do-i-convert-filenames-from-unicode-to-ascii

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**PREFACE:**

If you don't care about the case of your extensions, simply use the 'tr' utility in a shell loop:

```
for i in *.txt; do mv "$i" "$(echo "$i" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')"; done
```

If you do care about the case of the extensions, then you should be aware that there is more than one way to do it ([TIMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)). Personally, I believe the *Perl* solution, listed here, is probably the simplest and most flexible solution under Linux. If you have multiple file extensions, simply specify the number you wish to keep unchanged. The *BASH4* solution is also a very good one, but you must be willing to write out the extension a few times, or alternatively, use another variable to store it. But if you need serious portability then I recommend the last solution in this answer which uses octals. Some flavours of Linux also ship with a tool called *rename* that may also be worth checking out. It's usage will vary from distro to distro, so type `man rename` for more info.

**SOLUTIONS:**

Using **[Perl](http://www.kichwa.com/quik_ref/spec_variables.html)**:

```
# single extension
perl -e 's/\.[^\.]*$/rename $_, uc($`) . $&/e for @ARGV' *.txt

# multiple extensions
perl -e 's/(?:\.[^\.]*){2}$/rename $_, uc($`) . $&/e for @ARGV' *.tar.gz
```

---

Using **[BASH4](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PARAMSUBREF)**:

```
# single extension
for i in *.txt; do j="${i%.txt}"; mv "$i" "${j^^}.txt"; done

# multiple extensions
for i in *.tar.gz; do j="${i%.tar.gz}"; mv "$i" "${j^^}.tar.gz"; done

# using a var to store the extension:
e='.tar.gz'; for i in *${e}; do j="${i%${e}}"; mv "$i" "${j^^}${e}"; done
```

---

Using **[GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)**:

```
for i in *.txt; do

    mv "$i" $(echo "$i" | awk '{ sub(/.txt$/,""); print toupper($0) ".txt" }');
done
```

Using **[GNU sed](http://timmurphy.org/2013/02/24/converting-to-uppercase-lowercase-in-sed/)**:

```
for i in *.txt; do

    mv "$i" $(echo "$i" | sed -r -e 's/.*/\U&/' -e 's/\.TXT$/\u.txt/');
done
```

---

Using **[BASH3.2](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-sed-ascii-control-codes-nonprintable/)**:

```
for i in *.txt; do

    stem="${i%.txt}";

    for ((j=0; j<"${#stem}"; j++)); do

        chr="${stem:$j:1}"

        if [[ "$chr" == [a-z] ]]; then

            chr=$(printf "%o" "'$chr")

            chr=$((chr - 40))

            chr=$(printf '\'"$chr")
        fi

        out+="$chr"
    done

    mv "$i" "$out.txt"

    out=
done
```

Comment: n.b. sed solution not compatible with Mac/Darwin/BSD (non-Linux?) *sed*

Comment: @Orwellophile: GNU sed is not BSD sed. BSD is Linux like GNU is Linux.

Comment: It doesn't work with Solaris either.  (That's SYSV).  But your correction is noted.  It does not work with non-GNU versions of **sed**

Comment: @Orwellophile: Correction? I stated the fact almost two years ago. If you have a non-GNU system, then you have other more serious problems than just the case of your filenames.

Answer (score 9):

In general for lowercase/upper case modifications "tr" ( translate characters ) utility is often used, it's from the set of command line utilities used for character replacement.

```
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ echo "xxx" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'
XXX
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$
```

Also, for renaming files there's "rename" utility, delivered with perl ( man rename ).

```
    SYNOPSIS
       rename [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] perlexpr [ files ]

DESCRIPTION
       "rename" renames the filenames supplied according to the rule specified as the first argument.  The perlexpr argument is a Perl expression which is expected to modify the $_ string in
   Perl for at least some of the filenames specified.  If a given filename is not modified by the expression, it will not be renamed.  If no filenames are given on the command line,
   filenames will be read via standard input.

   For example, to rename all files matching "*.bak" to strip the extension, you might say

           rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak

   To translate uppercase names to lower, you'd use

           rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest using `rename`, if you only want to uppercase the filename and not the extension, use something like this:

```
rename -n 's/^([^.]*)\.(.*)$/\U$1\E.$2/' *
```

`\U` uppercases everything until `\E`, see [perlreref(1)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html). Remove the `-n` when your happy with the output.

Comment: You might add ^ and $ anchors, and explicitly require the '.', so the match doesn't depend on the regex section being greedy or lazy; just makes it more readable IMHO.

Comment: That fits better with what the OP wants. I've added your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in *.txt; do
  mv "$f" "`tr [:lower:] [:upper:] <<< "${f%.*}"`.txt"
done
```

Comment: That will capitalize the "txt" extension. Also, with bash, use a here-string: `tr [:upper] [:lower:] <<< "$f"`

Comment: @glennjackman Good point. `${f%.*}` should take care of that. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Bash 4 parameter expansion can perform case changes:

```
for i in *.txt; do
  i="${i%.txt}"
  mv "$i.txt" "${i^^?}.txt"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

bash:

```
for f in *.txt; do 
    no_ext=${f%.txt}
    mv "$f" "${no_ext^^}.txt"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier, lightweight and portable approach would be:

```
for i in *.txt
do 
    fname=$(echo $i | cut -d"." -f1 | tr [a-z] [A-Z])
    ext=$(echo $i | cut -d"." -f2)
    mv $i $fname.$ext
done
```

This would work on almost every version of BASH since we are using most common external utilities (cut, tr) found on every Unix flavour.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use (on terminal):

```
for i in *.txt; do mv $i `echo ${i%.*} | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]`.txt; done;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
printf "%s\n" *.txt | sed 'h;s/[^.]*/\U&/;H;g;s/\(.*\)\n/mv -v \1 /' | sh
```

or more simply:

```
printf "%s\n" *.txt | sed 'h;s/[^.]*/\U&/;H;g;s/\(.*\)\n/mv -v \1 /e'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in *.jar; do mv $i `echo ${i%} | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`; done;
```

this works for me.