# Script which replaces special ASCII keys with text

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, sed

I'm writing a script which converts special characters to text.

How can I arrange it so my script takes a csv file as input and executes sed commands on it?

```
FILENAME= ls -ltr| grep *.csv
```

```
sed -i 's/\xc3\x83/A/g' FILENAME #Ã <br>
sed -i 's/\xc3\x80/A/g' FILENAME #À<br>
sed -i 's/\xc3\x81/A/g' FILENAME #Á<br>
sed -i 's/\xc3\x82/A/g' FILENAME #Â<br>
sed -i 's/\xc3\x85/A/g' FILENAME #Å<br>
```

Comment: What if you do `for file in *csv`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash: Convert non-ASCII characters to ASCII](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975057/bash-convert-non-ascii-characters-to-ascii)

Comment: Copied the logic from http://stackoverflow.com/a/1975093/793796 : `for file in *.csv; do iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//translit < "$file" > "$file.ascii" && mv "$file.ascii" "$file"; done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the sed command as

```
sed -i 's/\xc3\x8[0-5]/A/g' FILENAME
```

To iterate through all the csv files in a directory and apply the sed

```
for FILENAME in *.csv
do
 sed -i 's/\xc3\x8[0-5]/A/g' $FILENAME
done
```