# How to romanize (transliterate, unidecode) strings in Bash?

Tags: bash

I have UTF formatted strings, especially place names, in different languages such as:

```
A="København"
B="北京市"
C="Skåne län"
```

I would like to convert them to:

```
A="Kobenhavn"
B="Beijing"
C="Skane-lan"
```

Basically, to be able to do what [unidecode](http://search.cpan.org/~sburke/Text-Unidecode-0.04/lib/Text/Unidecode.pm) does, but to do it in Bash. (I'm on Windows with MSys)

Can anyone point me somewhere?

Comment: `echo 'København' | perl -Mutf8 -MText::Unidecode -ne 'print unidecode($_)'` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975057/bash-convert-non-ascii-characters-to-ascii)

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed [unidecode from python](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) on your machine, you can directly pass argument in command line:

`$ echo "København, 北京市, Skåne län" | unidecode`

Output :

`Kobenhavn, Bei Jing Shi , Skane lan`

Answer (score 0):

[There](http://www.bash-scripting.ru/script/item/148) is a script for Russian letters only. Be careful: it does smth with files.
The working part is

```
en=`echo $name|sed 'y/абвгджзийклмнопрстуфхыэе/abvgdjzijklmnoprstufhyee/'|sed 's/[ьъ]//g; s/ё/yo/g; s/ц/ts/g; s/ч/ch/g; s/ш/sh/g; s/щ/sh/g; s/ю/yu/g; s/я/ya/g'`
```